# compile error when installing node.js

Tags: node.js

i just download https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.2/node-v4.2.2.tar.gz, and put it in my centos /home/node, then unzip, ./configure, and then make && make install

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/node/node-v4.2.2/out'
  g++ '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64' '-DENABLE_DISASSEMBLER' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_STATIC' -I../deps/v8  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -B/home/node/node-v4.2.2/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -O3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -O3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF /home/node/node-v4.2.2/out/Release/.deps//home/node/node-v4.2.2/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o.d.raw  -c -o /home/node/node-v4.2.2/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:29,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc:5:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In constructor â€˜v8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()â€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:353: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::IsEmpty() constâ€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:360: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocal(v8::Local<S>*) constâ€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:364: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜bool v8::WeakCallbackInfo<T>::IsFirstPass() constâ€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:430: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:469: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜usingâ€™
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In constructor â€˜v8::Global<T>::Global()â€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:790: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In constructor â€˜v8::Global<T>::Global(v8::Global<T>&&)â€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:815: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜v8::Global<T>& v8::Global<T>::operator=(v8::Global<S>&&)â€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:827: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:852: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜usingâ€™
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:1089: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:1095: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) constâ€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:3205: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/include/v8.h: In member function â€˜v8::Local<T> v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocalChecked()â€™:
../deps/v8/include/v8.h:7164: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/checks.h:9,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:31,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc:5:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckEQImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:123: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckEQImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:123: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckNEImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:124: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckNEImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:124: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckLEImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:125: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckLEImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:125: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckLTImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:126: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckLTImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:126: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckGEImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:127: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckGEImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:127: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckGTImpl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:128: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h: In function â€˜std::string* v8::base::CheckGTImpl(int, int, const char*)â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/logging.h:128: error: â€˜nullptrâ€™ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/base/platform/platform.h:29,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/utils.h:18,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/v8.h:34,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/accessors.cc:5:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:36: error: variable â€˜v8::base::Mutex v8::base::finalâ€™ has initializer but incomplete type
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:37: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:37: error: expected â€˜}â€™ before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:37: error: expected â€˜,â€™ or â€˜;â€™ before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:39: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â€˜;â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h: In function â€˜v8::base::NativeHandle& v8::base::native_handle()â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:63: error: â€˜native_handle_â€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:65: error: non-member function â€˜const v8::base::NativeHandle& v8::base::native_handle()â€™ cannot have cv-qualifier
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h: In function â€˜const v8::base::NativeHandle& v8::base::native_handle()â€™:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:65: error: new declaration â€˜const v8::base::NativeHandle& v8::base::native_handle()â€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:62: error: ambiguates old declaration â€˜v8::base::NativeHandle& v8::base::native_handle()â€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:66: error: â€˜native_handle_â€™ was not declared in this scope
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h: At global scope:
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:69: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜privateâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:89: error: â€˜friendâ€™ used outside of class
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:91: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:91: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:91: error: â€˜void v8::base::operator=(const v8::base::Mutex&)â€™ must be a nonstatic member function
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:104: error: expected initializer before â€˜<â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:130: error: variable â€˜v8::RecursiveMutex v8::finalâ€™ has initializer but incomplete type
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:131: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:131: error: expected â€˜}â€™ before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:131: error: expected â€˜,â€™ or â€˜;â€™ before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:133: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â€˜;â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:155: error: â€˜Mutexâ€™ has not been declared
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:155: error: expected initializer before â€˜NativeHandleâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:157: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â€˜&â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:160: error: expected initializer before â€˜&â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:164: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜privateâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:170: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:170: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:170: error: â€˜void v8::operator=(const v8::RecursiveMutex&)â€™ must be a nonstatic member function
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:184: error: expected initializer before â€˜<â€™ token
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:202: error: template declaration of â€˜LockGuard finalâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:203: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:203: error: expected â€˜}â€™ before â€˜publicâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:205: error: declaration of â€˜~LockGuardâ€™ as non-member
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:207: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜privateâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:210: error: expected unqualified-id before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:210: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜constâ€™
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:210: error: â€˜void operator=(const LockGuard&)â€™ must be a nonstatic member function
../deps/v8/src/base/platform/mutex.h:211: error: expected declaration before â€˜}â€™ token
make[1]: *** [/home/node/node-v4.2.2/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/node/node-v4.2.2/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

i had install python 2.6.6
how can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like some compiler issue, it seems like your g++ doesn't support c++11 features (`nullptr`). Perhaps you can try to update g++.

Answer (score 2):

Install g++ & gcc 4.8 or newer version https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3347

follow this to install it if you are using centos version lower than 7. https://gist.github.com/stephenturner/e3bc5cfacc2dc67eca8b